# Using EventScheduler does not trigger event handlers in Aggregate

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon

When I trigger a scheduled event via a Command, I do not see the expected Event Handlers trigger. I am trying to isolate a one-time business transaction in a Saga while still allowing Aggregates to be event sourced to be able to replay state changes.

---

I have configured the following `SimpleEventScheduler`.

```java
@Bean
public SimpleEventScheduler simpleEventScheduler(EventBus eventBus) {
    return SimpleEventScheduler.builder()
        .eventBus(eventBus)
        .scheduledExecutorService(scheduledExecutorService())
        .build();
    }

private ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService() {
    return Executors.unconfigurableScheduledExecutorService(Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor());
}
```

I have an aggregate modeled that has a `@CommandHandler`

```java
@CommandHandler
public Letter(ScheduleLetterCommand cmd, EventScheduler scheduler) {
    String id = cmd.getLetterId();
    log.info("Received schedule command for letter id {}", id);
    ScheduleToken scheduleToken = scheduler.schedule(Duration.ofSeconds(5), new BeginSendLetterEvent(id, LetterEventType.BEGIN_SEND));
    AggregateLifecycle.apply(new LetterScheduledEvent(id, LetterEventType.SCHEDULED, scheduleToken));
}
```

and two `@EventSourcingHandler`

```java
@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(BeginSendLetterEvent event) {
    log.info("Letter sending process started {} {}", event.getLetterId(), event.getEventType());
    scheduleToken = null;
}

@EventSourcingHandler
public void on(LetterSentEvent event) {
    log.info("Letter sent {} {}", event.getLetterId(), event.getEventType());
    this.sent = true;
}
```

I have a saga that does some 'business logic' when `BeginSendLetterEvent` is triggered and publishes `LetterSentEvent`.

```java
@Saga
@Slf4j
public class LetterSchedulingSaga {

    private EventGateway eventGateway;

    public LetterSchedulingSaga() {
        //Axon requires empty constructor
    }

    @StartSaga
    @EndSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "letterId")
    public void handle(BeginSendLetterEvent event) {
        log.info("Sending letter {}...", event.getLetterId());
        eventGateway.publish(new LetterSentEvent(event.getLetterId(), LetterEventType.SENT));
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setEventGateway(EventGateway eventGateway) {
        this.eventGateway = eventGateway;
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
com.flsh.web.LetterScheduler            : Received request to schedule letter
com.flsh.web.LetterScheduler            : Finished request to schedule letter
com.flsh.axon.Letter                    : Received schedule command for letter id b7338082-e0e1-4ba0-b137-c7ff92afe3a1
com.flsh.axon.Letter                    : LetterScheduledEvent b7338082-e0e1-4ba0-b137-c7ff92afe3a1 SCHEDULED
com.flsh.axon.LetterSchedulingSaga      : Sending letter b7338082-e0e1-4ba0-b137-c7ff92afe3a1...
```

The thing is I am not seeing the above two event handlers being triggered at all. Can someone see what I am doing wrong here? :) Any help would be appreciated...

If this is the wrong way to use Sagas and Event Handlers please let me know. I realize my rudimentary example doesn't facilitate a good domain model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your problem @GoldFish, is that you are expecting to handle events in your Command Model.

The aggregate in Axon terms is a Command Handling Component, as such being part of your Command Model when thinking about CQRS.
As such, it handles command messages and validates whether the given operation (read: command) can be executed. If the outcome of the validation is "yes", that's when you will end up publishing an event in the lifecycle of a given aggregate instances.

The `@EventSourcingHandler` annotated methods you can introduce into an aggregate are their to "source the aggregate instance based on **its own** events".

Having said that, you can anticipate that an Aggregate will **never** handle events directly from any other source then its own.

The `EventScheduler` is just as much an external source of events as another aggregate's events would be when sourcing. Hence, they will be disregarded for the aggregate.

The `EventScheduler` will publish an event at a latter stage, so that it might be handled by Event Handling Components, for example Saga instances.
If you want to schedule that something should occur for a **specific** aggregate or saga instance, you should have a look at the `DeadlineManager` instead.

Regardless, for what you're trying to achieve, which (I believe) is triggering an operation in your aggregate from a saga, you should use command messages, since the aggregate can only handle command messages.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Sorry I'm asking so many questions, I'm new to DDD/CQRS/EventSourcing and the axon framework so the concepts the API is referencing aren't immediately obvious to me. :) But I'm learning. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: No need to apologies @GoldFlsh! That's what StackOverflow is about, asking and answering questions.
I, for one, am happy to be able to help out.